# Concatenate List Object Name with a Number and Retain the List Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm using python 2.7 I'm trying to figure out a way to change the names of my lists automatically.

Let me explain i have multiple lists

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 
list2 = [4, 5, 9, 3]
list3 = [8, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

I would like to call the lists in a loop to determine which lists contain or do not contain a particular number.

My first thought was

```
x = "list" + str(i) # (where i iterates in the loop)
print x
```

However, using the above code only gave me the string "list1"(when i=1).

What I want is to be able to call the list that is named list1 and use the .count() operator to determine whether or not the number exists if it doesn't i want to call the next list until I'm out of lists(there will eventually be up to 30 lists).

Thanks,

Ryan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't approach it like this. Put your lists in a container to iterate over them instead:

```
In [5]: for l in (list1, list2, list3):
   ...:     print l.count(2)
   ...:     
1
0
1
```

What you could do in a real-life use case is create a list of lists and fill it dynamically.

Then to get the first list that contains a given number, you could do:

```
In [6]: lists = [list1, list2, list3]

In [7]: next(l for l in lists if 9 in l)
Out[7]: [4, 5, 9, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

put the list in dict:

```
list1 = [1,2.4]
list2 = [2,5,6]
dlist = {1:list1,2:list2}
for k in dlist:
   print dlist[k]
```